# Add CSS Class after HTML div using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class, insertafter

I have this HTML

```
            <div class="portItem"></div>
            <div class="portItem"></div>
            <div class="portItem"></div>
            <div class="portItem"></div>
```

This CSS

```
 .rectangle {
   height: 250px;
   width: 100%;
   position: relative;
   display: none;
   background: #ffffff;
   box-shadow: 1px 0px 20px black;
   overflow-y: hidden;}

      Here's the CSS for portItem, although not necessary (forms 4 green blocks next to each other)

     .portItem {
       height: 180px;
       width: 250px;
       position: relative;
       display: inline-block;
       background: #D0E182;
        margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
```

And I'm trying to add the CSS rectangle after any of the portItems that I click on.

Here's the JQuery function I'm trying to use:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.portItem').click(function() {
     addDiv($(this));
   });
 });



 function addDiv($ele) {
   var $box = $('<div />' '.rectangle');
   $box.insertAfter($ele);
 }
```

The problem is with the var $box statement, I can't get it to work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a comma, and an object.

```
var $box = $('<div />', {'class':'rectangle'});
// -------------------^ ^                   ^
//    added comma-----| |___________________|---and object literal syntax
```

---

The quotes around `class` are needed to support older browsers. You could also use `className` instead.

```
var $box = $('<div />', {className:'rectangle'});
```

Comment: Thanks! Also the fact that i had display:none... Changed that too and now it works

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
var $box = $('<div/>').addClass('rectangle');
```

... or as simple as...

```
var $box = $('<div class="rectangle"/>');
```

Actually, I might consider preparing this item first-hand, then just [cloning](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) it. For example:

```
var $boxTemplate = $('<div class="rectangle">');
function addDiv($ele) {
   $boxTemplate.clone().insertAfter($ele);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the var $box line to:

```
var $box = $('<div class="rectangle" />');
```